# How can I resolve `CocoaPods not installed` issue without quitting my visual studio application every time?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, cocoapods

I want to debug my Flutter application on my mac machine using visual studio code, and sometimes when trying to start debugging my app, I see the below error

```
Launching lib/main_staging.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
lib/main_staging.dart:1
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
Exited
```

not sure if the `visual studio code` is able to find `CocoaPods` even if it is installed.

I am able to resolve this issue on its own by using the `quit` option on mac and reopening the same project on visual studio code again.

I was also able to resolve this using the long process using the below commands, which sometimes resolves the issue and sometimes does not (not reliable)

```
    `flutter clean`
    `pod deintegrate`
    `pod install`
```

How can I resolve this issue without quitting my visual studio application every time?